# Represent a `Path` starting with a `\` but without a disk drive, under Windows

Tags: java, windows, jsr203

I do not own a Windows copy, but would like to know the behavior and recommended usage in Java for representing a path such as `\autoexec.bat` under Windows?

Semantically, such a path would represent the file `autoexec.bat` on the root of any file system. Thus it would need to be resolved against a path representing a disk drive (such as `C:\`) before representing a file. In that sense, it is not [absolute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#isAbsolute()). However, it also does not have a root component, I suppose.

Can such path be created when running the JVM on Windows? If so, what would `getRoot()` and `isAbsolute()` return?

I tried the following code using [Memory File System](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem), but this throws `InvalidPathException`: “path must not start with separator at index 1: \truc”. Does this faithfully reflect the behavior under Windows, or is it a quirk of this specific library?

```
try (FileSystem fs = MemoryFileSystemBuilder.newWindows().build()) {
    final Path truc = fs.getPath("\\truc");
    LOGGER.info("Root: {}.", truc.getRoot());
    LOGGER.info("Abs: {}.", truc.isAbsolute());
    LOGGER.info("Abs: {}.", truc.toAbsolutePath());
}
```

Such paths are valid in the Windows terminal, or at least they were last time I used Windows (a long time ago). It would be handy to create such path in order to mark that the path is “absolute” (in the sense of starting with a backslash, thus not relative to a folder), but still leave the path without a driver letter specified. Then such a path can be (later) resolved to `C:\autoexec.bat` or `D:\autoexec.bat` or …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows, `\\` refers to the current drive which is `C:\` in my case.

Not sure how the `MemoryFileSystemBuilder` works but the following code

```
File file = new File("\\test.txt");
final Path truc = file.toPath();
System.out.println("Root: " + truc.getRoot().toString());
System.out.println("Abs: " + truc.isAbsolute());
System.out.println("Abs: " + truc.toAbsolutePath().toString());
```

gives the below output

```
Root: \
Abs: false
Abs: C:\test.txt
```

Comment: *"In Windows, `\\ ` refers to the base system drive which is `C:\ ` in my case."* - This is incorrect. A filename starting with a single backslash designates an [absolute path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#fully-qualified-vs-relative-paths) on the **current volume**. This may or may not be the volume designated by `C:`. The volume may not even have a drive letter assigned. The system volume need not have the `C` drive letter assigned either.

Comment: You mean \, not \\, I suppose.

Comment: @OlivierCailloux In java, \ should be escaped. So, we use \\

Comment: I understand, but your first sentence reads as if you were talking about the path consisting of _two_ backslashes in Windows. You mean one, there. (Admittedly, I am nitpicking, but some readers might get confused perhaps.)